# How to run webpack-bundle-analyzer?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I installed `webpack-bundle-analyzer` and need to run it. How can I do it? I have several errors. One of the most common is

```
Could't analyze webpack bundle
```

Answer (score 53):

Finally I found that one can solve this issue by two ways. [See more](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer). In any case you need to add to **webpack.config.js**

```
var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
```

and to

```
plugins : [ 
  new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
    analyzerMode: 'server',
    generateStatsFile: true,
    statsOptions: { source: false }
  }),
  ...
],
```

Then if you want to look at the report html page in your browser each time you make a build, no actions are required.

If you want to run the report page from time to time using your CLI, then you need to disable server in the **webpack.config.js** like this:

```
plugins : [ 
  new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
    analyzerMode: 'disabled',
    generateStatsFile: true,
    statsOptions: { source: false }
  }),
  ...
],
```

and to add the row in the script section of your **package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
  "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer --port 4200 dist/stats.json",
  ...
}
```

I made the second choice.

Comment: Need a little fix `analyzerMode: 'disabled',`

Comment: I don't have a webpack confirg

Comment: FYI... The stats.json file will be generated in bundle output directory, not necessarily the dist folder

Comment: What is the motivation for specifying `statsOptions: { source: false }`? When I remove this line nothing seems to change.

Answer (score 9):

I have it set up as follows, which seems a bit cleaner. Followed this [very nice tutorial about Webpack Visualization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAgHZ9zlmaY&list=PLmZPx_9ZF_sB4orswXdpThGMX9ii2uP7Z&index=6).

webpack.config.js

```
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');

webpackConfig.plugins = [
  new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
    // use value from environment var STATS or 'disabled'
    analyzerMode: process.env.STATS || 'disabled',
  }),
];
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "APP_ENV=local PORT=443 webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.config.js",
  "build": "npm run clean && webpack --config webpack/webpack.config.js --
  "stats": "STATS=server npm run build"
},
```

Answer (score 3):

Another easy solution without any code change or ejecting from webpack is,

```
npx webpack-bundle-analyzer ./build/bundle-stats.json
```

In case, you get error about missing `bundle-stats.json`, then run the below command( which will generate the `bundle-stats.json` file) and then try the above command again

```
yarn run build -- --stats
```

So basically, while building, you inform that you need `build stats.json`, and you run first command in my comment, webpack-bundle-anaylzer will look through the bundle-stats.json

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by doing the following in my config:

```
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')
```

original line was:

```
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')
```

Answer (score 0):

For Angular I do:

```
ng build --stats-json
npx webpack-bundle-analyzer ./dist/stats.json
```